# Automatic height of the iframe window

Tags: iframe, browser, window, height, auto

I need the material, specifically the content of another page, to be loaded into the iframe and the iframe window must automatically set a new height after changing the content in this window.

I have this code to paste in the iframe:

```
https://demo.phpjabbers.com/1676400046_556/preview.php?cid=1&switch=1&multi=1&theme=theme1
```

On the page I use this code:

```
<iframe src="https://demo.phpjabbers.com/1676400046_556/preview.php?cid=1&switch=1&multi=1&theme=theme1" width="100%" height="700px" style="border:none;overflow :hidden"></iframe>
```

What needs to be done to make it work? The solutions provided here on the forum so far do not work in 2023.

view address:

```
https://taxigoldap.pl/taxi-online2
```

please help.